# Fiddler - how can I block outgoing requests to a specific URL?

Tags: browser, request, block, fiddler, rules

I'm using fiddler to test some new code on our site. Testing this code requires that I block all traffic from *my browser* to a specific URL. I need to see what would happen if this request does not work.

I can't figure out how to do this though, all of the guides just talk about blocking responses from a URL. I need the entire request to a specific URL to not work as if it was never sent. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear entirely what you mean. If you use an AutoResponder rule with a value of `*drop` or `*reset`, Fiddler will kill the connection via `FIN` or `RST` after it reads the request.

Answer (score 0):

**OnBeforeRequest**

```
       // Break requests for URLs containing "somehost.com"
        if (oSession.uriContains("somehost.com")) {
            oSession.oRequest.FailSession(404, "Blocked", "Fiddler blocked");
        }
```